# ios uitableview section index

Tags: ios, uitableview

how can I made my section index different from my section titles?

For example, lets say I have letters of cities in my section titles (A,B,C, etc) but I also want to add one to the top called 'Recent Cities'.  Now in the section index I dont want to show Recent Cities but something different like Rec or Re.

Is there some kind of override for this?  Maybe it is simpler than I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement `UITableViewDataSource` method like this

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rec", @"A", @"B", nil ];
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what im already doing but then this puts Rec in both the section header and the search index, so the search index becomes super wide.  I want the section index header to be 'Recent Cities' and the search index to say Re or Rec

Answer (score 0):

As beryllium said, this should be done in the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: method as part of the data source implementation.